# How to delete DB records without loading them into memory in LINQPad?

Tags: c#, linqpad

LINQPad allows to delete records from DB like this

```cs
var ids = new [] { 1, 2, 3 ... N };
var records = Table.Where(t => ids.Contains(t.Id)).ToList();

Table.DeleteAllOnSubmit(records);
SubmitChanges();
```

However it is overkill to load N records if needed to delete by Ids.

Installing EF or some other package? No native way?

@JoeAlbahari?

Comment: Lin**Q** is for **q**uerying.. It does not support data manipulation.

Comment: according to your logic @mat-j, why then LinQ allows Delete(All)OnSubmit and Insert ones? and yeap, why this queering tool allows updates?

Comment: If you are using Linq2Sql then you check out the LinqPost nuget package.

Comment: @svonidze - LINQ isn't LINQ2SWL not EF. Those are additions to LINQ.

Comment: @svonidze, those are not linq. So you are looking for a function and not linq option to delete?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create entities with these IDs and attach them to the table. After make a deletion query.

```
var ids = new[] { 1, 2, 3... N };

var records = ids.Select(x => new Record { Id = x }).ToArray(); // entity in Table

Table.AttachAll(records);

Table.DeleteAllOnSubmit(records);
SubmitChanges();
```

Answer (score 1):

in EF Core 7.0, use  [ExecuteDelete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-7.0/whatsnew#executeupdate-and-executedelete-bulk-updates)

```
var ids = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
var records = Temps.Where(t => ids.Contains(t.ID))
                .ExecuteDelete();
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You're not actually loading everything in your example.  The SQL isn't executed against the database until you call `ToList()`, at which point all the previous conditions are taken into account when generating the SQL statement.  In your example, it probably transforms into something like

```
SELECT id, ... FROM Table where id in (1, 2, 3)
```

Meaning (assuming `id`s are unique) you only get three rows, no matter how many rows are in the actual table.

---

If you only have a small list of IDs, you can enter straight SQL into LinqPad by selecting it in the language dropdown.

```
delete from Table where id in (1, 2, 3);
```

Or you can generate a SQL delete statement as a string and execute it against the database using `ExecuteCommand`.

I'm afraid I've not found any easier way of deleting records than that.

Comment: I replaced "everything" with N records to be clear.
"straight SQL" is a way for sure, but I would like to use C# only.
thank you for your answer.